# How to format data while adding in generic List

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am trying to add all the data from `DataTable` into `List<string> dataFromDataTable = new List<string>();` for which I have written a c# code. later On I need to convert it into Json.

Here is the code.

```
List<string> dataFromDataTable = new List<string>();

for (int r = 0; r < employees.Rows.Count; r++)
{
   dataFromDataTable.Add("{".ToString());
   for (int c = 0; c < employees.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
      dataFromDataTable.Add(employees.Rows[r][c].ToString());
    }
   dataFromDataTable.Add("}".ToString());
}
```

and here is my json code.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(sample);
```

As of Now I am getting json like.

```
["John Doe","Fresno","Billy","Fresno","Tom","Kern","King Smith","Kings"]
```

whereas I need it like

```
["John Doe","Fresno"],["Billy","Fresno"],["Tom","Kern"],["King Smith","Kings"]]
```

How to di it.Thanks

Comment: What does contain the `sample` variable?

Comment: @IvanStoev It contains data that is in `dataFromDataTable`

Comment: i.e. `List<string>` with something like "{", "John Doe", "Freshno", "}" inside

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes you are right

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried to add `dataFromDataTable.Add("{".ToString());` at the start of first for loop and also tried to close at the end to format it in the required but I am getting  double quotes and comma . Comma is coming before double quotes with every time loop runs

Comment: The answer by @shakib should produce the output you are after.

Comment: @IvanStoev tried to implement the solution but getting error while assigning it at public List<string> tabledata { get; set; } I need to assign the tabledata but getting can not implicitly convert error. How to resolve it?

Comment: You need to change the type from `List<string>` to `List<object[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = employees.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
```

hope this helps

Comment: tried to implement the solution but getting error while assigning it at `public List<string> tabledata { get; set; }` I need to assign the `tabledata` but getting `can not implicitly convert error`. How to resolve it

Comment: @Lara how about mine, it still the same concept :3 and first answer

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do it like this :

```
  var list = employees.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            new 
            {
                FirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName"), // Column name was not specified please change this
                LastName = row.Field<string>("LastName") // As well as this column
            }).ToList();

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(list);
```

Take Note, it's a best practice to add keys in your objects so in our example `FirstName` and `LastName` are added.